# log4j how to use default encoding

Tags: java, logging, encoding, log4j2

When I printing a cyrillic string in the Windows console, System.out.println prints it normally, but log4j logger.info do not

My code:

```java
package org.example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {
    public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cyrillic = "привет"; // some cyrillic string

        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().name()); // windows-1251
        System.out.println(cyrillic); // prints string normally
        logger.info(cyrillic); // prints "яЁштхЄ"
    }
}
```

Output in console:

[image]

My log4j2.properties file:

```
# Extra logging related to initialization of Log4j
# Set to debug or trace if log4j initialization is failing
status=off
# Name of the configuration
name=MainConfiguration

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=[%d{HH:mm:ss}/%p]: [%c{1}] %m%n

# Root logger level
rootLogger.level=INFO
# Root logger referring to console appender
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=consoleLogger
```

It looks like println uses Charset.defaultCharset(), but logger.info() doesn't use it and uses UTF-8, so how do I tell log4j to use the default terminal encoding, the same as println?

like appender.console.layout.charset=DEFAULT

Also if it uses default encoding already, why output is different?